# Displaying users numbers on mysql without issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 simple tables, like below

**`users`**

```
id   name     surname
1    John     Douglas
2    Sam      Morris
3    Michael  Johnatan
```

**`cells`**

```
id   userId     cellPhone
1    1         13809876543
2    1         13809876525
3    2         13809876450
```

The result, which I want to get at the end only using Mysql:

**`result`**

```
name     surname     cellPhone
John     Douglas     13809876543,13809876525
Sam      Morris      13809876450
Michael  Johnatan
```

Here is my sql query

```
SELECT
    o.name,
    o.surname,
    CONCAT(ons.cellPhone, ',', ons2.cellPhone) as CellPhone
FROM
    users as o
LEFT JOIN cells as ons
    ON o.id = ons.userId
LEFT JOIN cells as ons2
    ON o.id = ons2.userId AND
       ons.id NOT LIKE ons2.id
GROUP BY o.id
```

So, in this case, at the end I get this result:

**`result`**

```
Name     Surname     Phones
John     Douglas     13809876543,13809876525
Sam      Morris      
Michael  Johnatan
```

You can see, sql does not display the phones of Sam. As I understand, it displays when user have 2 phone numbers. I tried a lot to fix it. I would appreciated, if someone helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    users.name,
    users.surname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(cells.cellPhone) as CellPhone
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN cells
    ON users.id = cells.userId
GROUP BY users.id
```

Reference:

- [GROUP_CONCAT(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)